# Disable selecting a range in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane that i want the user to be able to edit normally, but i don't want the user to select a range of characters; i just want a cursor.  How would i do this?  Using JTextPane's setSelectionStart and setSelectionEnd works most of the time, but not always.

```
boolean selectionAlreadyHandled = false;
JTextPane jtextpane;

public void caretUpdate (CaretEvent evt)
  {
  if (selectionAlreadyHandled)
    {
    selectionAlreadyHandled = false;
    return;
    }

  int pos = evt.getDot();
  if (pos != evt.getMark())
    {
    selectionAlreadyHandled = true;
    if (pos < evt.getMark())
      jtextpane.setSelectionEnd(pos);
    if (pos > evt.getMark())
      jtextpanel.setSelectionBegin(pos);
    }

  //Event handling
  return;
  }
```

Comment: can you post your code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

This should probably do it. And if it doesn't, I don't know if anything will

```
public class MyTextPane extends JTextPane {
  public void setSelectionStart(int spot) {
    super.setSelectionStart(spot);
    super.setSelectionEnd(spot);
  }

  public void setSelectionEnd(int spot) {
    super.setSelectionStart(spot);
    super.setSelectionEnd(spot);
  }

  public void select(int start, int end) {
    super.select(start, start);
  }
}
```